# trie data structure C

Tags: c, data-structures

ok so i define my structure like this.

```
    struct trie {
        struct trie *child[26];
        int count;
        char letter;
    };
```

the problem is when i try to fill my trie with words i get a segmentation fault.
ive been told that the problem is that the child variable isn't pointing to anything and setting them to NULL would fix this. Also creating a second structure would be a good way to achieve this. i am new to C programming and am confused on how to create a second structure to achieve this. any help would be much appreciated.

```
int addWordOccurrence(const char* word)
{

    struct trie *root;
    root = (struct trie *)malloc(sizeof(struct trie*));
    struct trie *initRoot=root;
    int count;

    int x=strlen(word);
    printf("%d",x);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    {  
        int z=word[i]-97;
        if(word[i]=='\n')
        {
            z=word[i-1]-97;
            root->child[z]->count++;
            root=initRoot;
        }

        root->child[z] = (struct trie *)malloc(sizeof(struct trie));
        root->child[z]->letter=word[i];
        root->child[z]=root;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to allocate memory for the pointers in `child`. Do you know `malloc`/`calloc`? Or you create other `trie`s and put them in. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Is this C or C++?  The answers will differ wildly.

Comment: Where is the code for filling your trie?

Comment: yes i use malloc in my method that adds the words to the trie.

Comment: The struct definition looks OK (though I don't know what `count` is for), but you haven't posted the code for inserting, and that's where the problem is. Please post that code.

Comment: If you post a minimal program that compiles and exhibits the error, we can try it (no pun intended) and help you more effectively.

Comment: my string that is getting inserting looks like "cat\ndog\napple\n"

Comment: the count variable is added at the last letter of the word to signify that it is complete and to keep track of occurrences

Comment: waitasecond, I just realized this function adds all the words to a local trie that's never returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root->child[z] = (struct trie *)malloc(sizeof(struct trie));
root->child[z]->letter=word[i];
root->child[z]=root;
```

This is problematic.
1) What if `child[z]` was already set?
2) You never set `child[z]->child` or `child[z]->count` to anything

#2 is causing your segfaults, #1 is a memory leak.

My solution would be to write a function for allocating new children:

```
struct trie* newtrie(char newchar) {
    struct trie* r = malloc(sizeof(struct trie));
    memset(r, 0, sizeof(struct trie));
    r->letter = newchar;
    return r;
}
```

Then your code would become:

```
    if (root->child[z] == NULL)
        root->child[z] = newtrie(word[i]);
    root->child[z]=root;
```

You also have to change the malloc of root:

```
struct trie *root = newtrie(0);
```

Which is more clear, and avoids the errors I mentioned.  http://codepad.org/J6oFQJMb  No segfaults after 6 or so calls.

I've also noticed that your code `malloc`s a new `root`, but never returns it, so nobody except this function can ever see it.  This is also a memory leak.

Comment: should i use malloc for the children when i define the structure?

Comment: ug i appreciate your help, maybe im just implementing it wrong but i am still getting the seg fault

Comment: Mark, you might be implementing it in the wrong way or you might have misunderstood the answer. I think you should edit your question and add more information (for example put there the new version of your source code) and you'll suddenly get much more answers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @MooingDuck's answer, there is another problem with your code here:

```
int addWordOccurrence(const char* word)
{

    struct trie *root;
    root = (struct trie *)malloc(sizeof(struct trie*));
    struct trie *initRoot=root;
    int count;
    /* ... */
}
```

You did a

```
root = (struct trie *)malloc(sizeof(struct trie*));
```

but you really mean to allocate the `sizeof(struct trie), and not sizeof a pointer (which will likely be 4 or 8 if you're on x86 or x86_64).

This is better (don't need explicit cast of `malloc`'s return pointer in C, and you can do `sizeof` like this:

```
struct tree *root = malloc(sizeof(*root));
```